# Shakespearean Sonnets within his plays

Tags: poetry, william-shakespeare

The prologue to *Romeo and Juliet* is a sonnet. Are there other moments, sections within the plays that are sonnets?

I'd like a list of Shakespearean sonnets which appear in his plays (not in the 154 sonnet long grouping usually called The Sonnets) whether as a prologue, post script, or anything else.

Answer (score 9):

There are sonnets in several of Shakespeare's plays, especially, though not exclusively, in his earlier ones.

Best know among these may be the one that **Romeo and Juliet** share in [Act 1, scene 5](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/romeo_juliet/romeo_juliet.1.5.html):

> ROMEO
> [To JULIET] If I profane with my unworthiest hand
> This holy shrine, the gentle fine is this:
> My lips, two blushing pilgrims, ready stand
> To smooth that rough touch with a tender kiss.
>
> JULIET
> Good pilgrim, you do wrong your hand too much,
> Which mannerly devotion shows in this;
> For saints have hands that pilgrims' hands do touch,
> And palm to palm is holy palmers' kiss.
>
> ROMEO
> Have not saints lips, and holy palmers too?
>
> JULIET
> Ay, pilgrim, lips that they must use in prayer.
>
> ROMEO
> O, then, dear saint, let lips do what hands do;
> They pray, grant thou, lest faith turn to despair.
>
> JULIET
> Saints do not move, though grant for prayers' sake.
>
> ROMEO
> Then move not, while my prayer's effect I take.

And they immediately begin another sonnet but they are interrupted by Juliet's nurse.

Another sonnet can be found in the [Prologue to Act 2](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/romeo_juliet/romeo_juliet.2.0.html):

> Now old desire doth in his death-bed lie,
> And young affection gapes to be his heir;
> That fair for which love groan'd for and would die,
> With tender Juliet match'd, is now not fair.
> Now Romeo is beloved and loves again,
> Alike betwitched by the charm of looks,
> But to his foe supposed he must complain,
> And she steal love's sweet bait from fearful hooks:
> Being held a foe, he may not have access
> To breathe such vows as lovers use to swear;
> And she as much in love, her means much less
> To meet her new-beloved any where:
> But passion lends them power, time means, to meet
> Tempering extremities with extreme sweet.

***Love's Labour's Lost*** contains several sonnets, for example the one read by Nathanael in Act 4, scene 2:

> If love make me forsworn, how shall I swear to love?
> Ah, never faith could hold, if not to beauty vowed!
> Though to myself forsworn, to thee I’ll faithful prove;
> Those thoughts to me were oaks, to thee like osiers bowed.
> Study his bias leaves and makes his book thine eyes,
> Where all those pleasures live that art would comprehend.
> If knowledge be the mark, to know thee shall suffice.
> Well learned is that tongue that well can thee commend,
> All ignorant that soul that sees thee without wonder;
> Which is to me some praise, that I thy parts admire.
> Thy eye Jove’s lightning bears, thy voice his dreadful thunder,
> Which, not to anger bent, is music and sweet fire.
> Celestial as thou art, O, Pardon love this wrong,
> That sings heaven’s praise with such an earthly tongue.

This "sonnet" is unusual in that it consists of hexameters instead of pentameters.

In [Act 4, scene 3](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/lll/lll.4.3.html) Longaville reads a sonnet:

> Did not the heavenly rhetoric of thine eye,
> 'Gainst whom the world cannot hold argument,
> Persuade my heart to this false perjury?
> Vows for thee broke deserve not punishment.
> A woman I forswore; but I will prove,
> Thou being a goddess, I forswore not thee:
> My vow was earthly, thou a heavenly love;
> Thy grace being gain'd cures all disgrace in me.
> Vows are but breath, and breath a vapour is:
> Then thou, fair sun, which on my earth dost shine,
> Exhalest this vapour-vow; in thee it is:
> If broken then, it is no fault of mine:
> If by me broke, what fool is not so wise
> To lose an oath to win a paradise?

Dumain's poem from the same scene is also "sonnet" that uses seven-syllable lines instead of pentameters:

> On a day--alack the day!--
> Love, whose month is ever May,
> Spied a blossom passing fair
> Playing in the wanton air:
> Through the velvet leaves the wind,
> All unseen, can passage find;
> That the lover, sick to death,
> Wish himself the heaven's breath.
> Air, quoth he, thy cheeks may blow;
> Air, would I might triumph so!
> But, alack, my hand is sworn
> Ne'er to pluck thee from thy thorn;
> Vow, alack, for youth unmeet,
> Youth so apt to pluck a sweet!

The three "sonnets" from Act 4, scene 3 were pirated by the unscrupulous printer [William Jaggard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Jaggard), who included them in an anthology entitled [The Passionate Pilgrim](https://williamshakespeare.net/the-passionate-pilgrim.jsp), which he attributed in its entirety to Shakespeare, even though not all poems in the volume were actually by Shakespeare.

The Chorus at the end of [***Henry V***](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/henryv/henryv.5.2.html) also uses the sonnet form:

> Thus far, with rough and all-unable pen,
> Our bending author hath pursued the story,
> In little room confining mighty men,
> Mangling by starts the full course of their glory.
> Small time, but in that small most greatly lived
> This star of England: Fortune made his sword;
> By which the world's best garden be achieved,
> And of it left his son imperial lord.
> Henry the Sixth, in infant bands crown'd King
> Of France and England, did this king succeed;
> Whose state so many had the managing,
> That they lost France and made his England bleed:
> Which oft our stage hath shown; and, for their sake,
> In your fair minds let this acceptance take.

Helen's letter to the countess in [Act 3, scene 4 of ***All's Well That Ends Well***](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/allswell/allswell.3.4.html) is also a sonnet:

> I am Saint Jaques' pilgrim, thither gone:
> Ambitious love hath so in me offended,
> That barefoot plod I the cold ground upon,
> With sainted vow my faults to have amended.
> Write, write, that from the bloody course of war
> My dearest master, your dear son, may hie:
> Bless him at home in peace, whilst I from far
> His name with zealous fervor sanctify:
> His taken labours bid him me forgive;
> I, his despiteful Juno, sent him forth
> From courtly friends, with camping foes to live,
> Where death and danger dogs the heels of worth:
> He is too good and fair for death and me:
> Whom I myself embrace, to set him free.